# Backbone: not correct view after redirect

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to Backbone and have an issue from almous beginning wondering how to overcome issue with unexpected behavior of a main view.
 1. I launch page and it looks okey.
 2. I click button that lead me to different view and shows me it well.
 3. I click "back" button and I see a blank page, but in DOM I can find some elements from previous view, but not visible.

Here is a piece of my router code (I hope this pieces will be enough):

```
home: function () {
    if (!app.leftMenuView) {
        app.leftMenuView = new app.views.LeftMenuView({
            el: $("#left_menu")
        });
    } else {
        app.leftMenuView.delegateEvents();
    }
    if (!app.homeView) {
        app.homeView = new app.views.HomeView({
            el: $("#main_container")
        });
    } else {
        app.homeView.delegateEvents();
    }
    if (!app.topMenuView) {
        app.topMenuView = new app.views.topMenuView({
            el: $("#top_menu")
        });
    } else {
        app.topMenuView.delegateEvents();
    }
},
search: function () {
    app.searchView = new app.views.SearchView({
        el: $("body")
    });
},
```

A piece of main html file:

```
<body>
     <div id="search-div"></div>
     ...
</body>
```

HomeView:

```
app.views.HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.render()
    },
    render: function () {
        var self = this;
        $.get('/template/home.html', function (data) {
            self.$el.html(_.template(data)({}));
        });
        return this;
    },
});
```

A SearchView:

```
app.views.SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click #left-arrow-icon": "toMainPage"
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        var self = this;
        $.get('/template/searchView.html', function (data) {
            self.$el.html(_.template(data));
        });
        return this;
    },
    toMainPage: function () {
        Backbone.history.history.back();
    },
});
```

Comment: That `Backbone.history.history.back();` looks weird, why don't you just ` window.history.back()`? I feel like you just implemented _another back button_. I would reconsider this idea.

Comment: `window.history.back()` makes no difference. My app is very simple for now and I have only one back buttons. I checked all my views and only in one place I have a "back" event registered and only for one specyfied element.

Comment: `find some elements from previous view` what does that mean ? Changing the route didn't worked and the old view remained and got hidden through a `display:none` on the container, were all elements hidden or only a few ? More code is required, show the routes and clarify 3rd point i.e. coming from which view to which view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Finally I have solved this by appending my views to different containers and hiding them under some situations.

Answer (score 0):

In the example provided, the search view, if rendered, will destroy the main html file content since the element provided is directly the body. In any case, if you go to search view, your home page will have been destroyed or will not be able to render anymore.

I would suggest an improved layout management :

- separate elements per views
- show/hide of root elements based on routes